# phpMyAdmin hiding syntax errors on bulk INSERT statements?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to import large `.sql` files using phpMyAdmin, it is not reporting syntax errors. Every time it just gives back "1 command was successfully executed". Then I look into the table and see it is empty.

If I edit the `.sql` file manually and wrap it with `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` statements, it reports the error, as expected.

I'm worried that maybe something is misconfigured somewhere. The data I was actually using is confidential, but I was able to reproduce the problem with the following test data:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field1` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `field2` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `field3` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Contents of `no_error_message.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO `test`(field1,field2,field3) VALUES
(1,2,3),
(1,2,2),
(1,2,3),
(1,2,2),
-- ... around 20,000 similar rows
(1,,3),
-- oops syntax error
(1,2,5);
```

It only happens if the sql file is very large like this.

- phpMyAdmin version 4.0.4.1
- php version 5.2.14
- MySQL Server version 5.1.69

Data was imported using the import functionality in phpMyAdmin. And like I said, it magically notices the syntax errors when I make it into a transaction. Is this just a bug (if so, in which package, and does it happen in up-to-date versions), or is there something else going on here? I tend to be overly paranoid when it comes to databases.

I haven't been able to find anything useful in Google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why it reports the error only under "transactions", but I would suggest that you run some sort of verification script against your .sql file to check for missing or invalid entries in the VALUE lists, before feeding it to phpMyAdmin. Also, is everything under one INSERT or is it broken up into multiple INSERTs with a reasonable number of VALUE sets per statement? You might see if it then starts reporting syntax errors with smaller groups of data (say, a few hundred sets at a time).

Comment: It seems wholly dependent on the file size. One insert statement with a few hundred values returns an error if there is one. Verification is a good idea of course. If I send the statements to the prepared statement generator from php, that would probably work, right? Or is there some kind of lint mode for the commandline client or something?

Comment: You might be running into some sort of undocumented limit, or even a bug. It never hurts to break up huge INSERT statements into bite-sized pieces. I wouldn't be surprised if there was some sort of "lint" to validate SQL input, but it should be easy enough to knock off something in PHP or Perl to check the validity. I don't understand the bit about "sending statements to the prepared statement generator". Are these bad INSERTs already being generated by some program?

Comment: No, they were generated poorly by me. That bug has been fixed. The behavior was nonetheless confusing and counter-intuitive. Maybe I can see if appending `EXPLAIN` will trigger the syntax error for verification.